# iOS no longer suggesting passwords

Tags: ios, password, keychain, mobile-safari

I’m running iOS 12 on an iPhone 6 and Safari no longer gives an auto-suggested password when creating new online accounts.

Am I misremembering that this feature existed at one point or is there some new way to access this feature or otherwise turn Safari suggested passwords back on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Strong Passwords suggestion isn’t showing up, it means you don’t have iCloud Keychain enabled.

Go to **Settings** -> **Accounts & Passwords** -> **AutoFill Passwords** and **enable iCloud Keychain**.

Comment: I went **Settings** > **iCloud** > **Keychain** and then toggled that off and back on. It seemed to do the trick.

Comment: The above “fix” did not work for me. My settings were already enabled, but I turned them off then back on, and still no new suggestions for creating a strong password on a new website. It I have an iPhone 11. It supposedly needs a software update, but it refuses to install. Is this a different problem since I can’t install an os update?

Comment: @NoelKomuda not being able to update the OS should probably get resolved first.